# iText header for html

Tags: header, itext

I am generating a PDF using itext 5.0.5.I am reading different mime types image,pdf,html content etc. and then reading those files from database and generating pdf.

There are two type of document user can view a individual document and a collection of documents in one single generated pdf.

I HAVE ONE PROBLEM WITH HTML content pdf header part.This html content is coming from a text area on a form,there a user will get the header information prepoulated in text area then he can type and create document.At the time of pdf generation if i am using page event to generate the header for each page for every mime type document.

For html content the header is coming two times.What i want to do is for html type document on first page header should not be generated for first page.I got the solution for pdf if i am reading the individual document but when i am reading the final pdf which is containing all documents of different mime types then it's not working.Is there any way so that i can do like header will not be generated for html type content's first page for rest of pages it will be generated using page event.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use two different pageEvents when dealing with HTML.  One that added headers (the current one), and one that set the page event handler to the original one.

You start off with the new one.  The first page event comes along, and that new event handler changes the current page event handler.  The remaining pages are stamped with headers as usual.